# Rspec Test CanCan AbilityClass not building rules in Rails3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails, cancan

In my Test environment Cancan does not build its rules.

**ability.rb**

```
class Ability
 include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new 

    if user.is_admin?
      can :manage, :all
    end
    ....
  end
 end
```

When i start the development console and i do the following

```
 u = User.where(role: "admin").first
 u.ability.can?(:read, Order)        #true
 a = Ability.new(u)
 a.instance_values["rules"]          #gives [0] #<CanCan::Rule:0x000055f2637ece48 @match_all=false, @base_behavior=true, @actions=[:read], @subjects=[Order(id: integer, ....
```

shows that everything works fine. The rules are set. Doing the same in `rails c test` the 
`a.instance_values["rules"]` is empty

```
 u = User.where(role: "admin").first
 u.ability.can?(:read, Order)        #false
 a = Ability.new(u)
 a.instance_values["rules"]          #gives []
```

As a result the test

```
RSpec.describe Ability do
  describe 'User' do
    describe "abilities" do
      context "when is an  Admin" do
       subject(:admin){ AdminAbility.new(create(:admin_user)) }
         it do  
           puts admin.can? :read, Order #false
           puts admin.ability.can? :read, Order #false
           puts admin.instance_values["rules"]      # nil   ?
           expect(admin).to be_able_to(:read, Order)
         end 
         it {expect(admin).to be_able_to(:read, User) }
        end 
       end 
      end 
    end
```

fails not suprisingly with

```
** Failure/Error: it {expect(admim).to be_able_to(:read, Order)}
   expected to be able to :read Order(...)**
```

During the test run the `rules` key is not present (nil) in the `instance_values` hash.
There are generated  correctly for the development(and production)environment.
(I tested the FactorySetup for the roles and the Adminuser, this is not the problem)

Setup:
Rails: 3.2.22.2
Rspec: 3.8
CanCan: 1.6.10

Comment: Strange, are you sure `Ability` is not overriden somewhere in the test code? I'd grep got `Ability` in `spec/` dir, just in case

Comment: Hey thanks for the thought, i did check that indeed. Ability is just defined once.